# Unreliable fetching of google docs using document api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-docs-api

I am having an app at google app engine and in a piece of code I read a google document using Document APIs. The code looks like:

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            DocsService client = new DocsService("sakshum-YourAppName-v1");
            client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters,
                    new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
            URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
            DocumentQuery dquery = new DocumentQuery(feedUrl);
            dquery.setTitleQuery(title);
            dquery.setTitleExact(true);
            dquery.setMaxResults(10);
            DocumentListFeed resultFeed = client.getFeed(dquery,
                    DocumentListFeed.class);
```

and it fails with exception:

```
vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode getGoogleDoc: Exception is :Unable to complete the HTTP request
```

This happens not all the time but sometimes. So, what should be the right way to handle this failure situation? Is it a problem with GAE apis being very unreliable? it is a code issue which I can fix to handle it in a better way or something else?

Comment: Having a similar problem trying to write to a GD spreadsheet using the API: "error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable".  Also intermittent.